# can't improve query performance of query

Tags: mysql

I have the following 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  ID INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  AccountID INT NOT NULL,
  Type VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  ValidForBilling BOOLEAN NULL DEFAULT false,  
  MerchantCreationTime TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID),
  UNIQUE KEY (OrderID, Type)
);
```

with the index:
`INDEX accID_type_merchCreatTime_vfb (AccountID, Type, MerchantCreationTime, ValidForBilling);`

```
CREATE TABLE table2 (
  OrderID INT NOT NULL,
  AccountID INT NOT NULL,
  LineType VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
  CreationDate TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  CalculatedAmount NUMERIC(4,4) NULL,
  table1ID INT(11) NOT NULL
);
```

I'm running the following query:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(CalculatedAmount), 0.0) AS CalculatedAmount
FROM table2
       INNER JOIN table1  ON table1.ID = table2.table1ID
WHERE table1.ValidForBilling is TRUE
  AND table1.AccountID = 388
  AND table1.Type = 'TPG_DISCOUNT'
  AND table1.MerchantCreationTime >= '2018-11-01T05:00:00'
  AND table1.MerchantCreationTime < '2018-12-01T05:00:00';
```

And it takes about 2 minutes to complete.
I did `EXPLAIN` in order to try and improve the query performance and got the following output:

```
+----+-------------+------------------+------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------+----------------------+-------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table            | partitions | type   | possible_keys                                                                                                                                                                                        | key                           | key_len | ref                  | rows  | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+------------------+------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------+----------------------+-------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | table1           | NULL       | range  | PRIMARY,i_fo_merchant_time_account,FO_AccountID_MerchantCreationTime,FO_AccountID_ExecutionTime,FO_AccountID_Type_ExecutionTime,FO_AccountID_Type_MerchantCreationTime,accID_type_merchCreatTime_vfb | accID_type_merchCreatTime_vfb | 61      | NULL                 | 71276 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | table2           | NULL       | eq_ref | table1ID,i_oc_fo_id                                                                                                                                                                                  | table1ID                      | 4       | finance.table1.ID    |     1 |   100.00 | NULL                     |
+----+-------------+------------------+------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------+----------------------+-------+----------+--------------------------+
```

I see that I scan 71276 rows in `table1` and I can't seem to make this number lower.
Is there an index I can create to improve this query performance?

Comment: Assuming innodb, what `innodb_buffer_pool_size` do you have?  2mins is slow for close to good indexing.

Comment: your schema and your quety don't contain the same column's names

Comment: @scaisEdge fixed my schema sorry for that

Comment: @danblack `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is 6G

Comment: You can't use ISO8601 format strings like '2018-11-01T05:00:00', use '2018-11-01 05:00:00'

Answer (score 0):

Move `ValidForBilling` before `MerchantCreationTime` in `accID_type_merchCreatTime_vfb`. You need to do ref lookups `=TRUE` before range uses in an index.

For table 2, seems to be a table1ID index already and appending CalculatedAmount will be able to be used in the result:

```
CREATE INDEX tbl1IDCalcAmount (table1ID,CalculatedAmount) ON table2
```

Comment: sorry fixed the schema, i have both `table1ID` and `OrderID` columns

Comment: moved `ValidForBilling` but it now picks the index named `FO_AccountID_Type_MerchantCreationTime` which is
 `(AccountId, Type, MerchantCreationTime)` without `ValidForBilling`